# Build debug version of Boost on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, boost, build, centos, bjam

I'm trying to build a debug version of Boost on CentOS 7 with the following command:

`./b2 runtime-link=shared runtime-debugging=on variant=debug link=shared install`

However, I don't see the `g` nor `d` ABI flag in the names of the generated library files. Have I done something wrong? Everything works just fine when building on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that should work.

If building like you do and inspecting one of the resulting libs with objdump

```
objdump --syms libboost_wave.so | grep debug
```

I get

```
...
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_aranges 0000000000000000              .debug_aranges
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_info    0000000000000000              .debug_info
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_abbrev  0000000000000000              .debug_abbrev
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_line    0000000000000000              .debug_line
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_str     0000000000000000              .debug_str
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_ranges  0000000000000000              .debug_ranges
...
```

If building without "runtime-debugging=on variant=debug" the corresponding result do not result in any matches for "grep debug".

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. The naming convention seems to apply to Windows build only. The Boost doc is simply incorrect.