# How to build a version of Boost with _GLIBCXX_DEBUG?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, boost

When debugging my code, I like to build it with `-g -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` GCC flags (and no `-O3 -DNDEBUG`). Unfortunately, using these flags prevents it from linking with "normal" Boost.

Is there a simple recipe for building Boost with custom GCC flags like this? ([Another SO question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33497658/build-debug-version-of-boost-on-centos-7) doesn't seem to cover `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build the `boost` libraries as described here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

You can specify the macros for the `boost` libraries on the `b2` command line by adding: `define=MACRO_NAME=MACRO_VALUE` for each macro.